# How to save previous fetched data through importhtml or other functions in google sheets when they stopped working or gets error?

Tags: google-sheets, import

I have prepared a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PbEcq9gErXVdXDSzrBe4a7shIBrTaClFH0ICchxD8dY/edit#gid=0), I fetch external data in {A3:J} using importhtml function, and save it in {L3:U}.

The problem is that, when the error '#N/A' gets during fetching the data in {A3:A} ([Pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf8Xp.jpg)), previous fetched/stored data in {L3:U} also gets deleted and shows '#N/A'. So, please help/suggest me any command/formula/function to remains store previous fetched data in {L3:U} and automatically replace {L3:U} the data when new update/refresh.

I need to remains save the latest updated data in {L3:U} when gets error. [sheet attaches](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PbEcq9gErXVdXDSzrBe4a7shIBrTaClFH0ICchxD8dY/edit#gid=0).

Comment: About `when new update/refresh`, how does this occur in your situation?

Comment: Imported data is continuously changing after certain interval as fetched by Google sheet. And I want to store last values obtained through importhtml.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Imported data is continuously changing after certain interval as fetched by Google sheet`, how will you detect this change? And, for example, if a cell value is `#N/A` and you put the old value into the cell, all cell values have both new and old data. Is this your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your response. But, my Expected result is the array stored in {L3:U}, when the array {A3:J} is non empty and not contains #N/A or any other error. Means the value deleted in cell {A3:J} then the value remains reflect in the array {L3:U}.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Actually, I am apologizing for my poor skill. My words are unable to understand you. However, the cells {L3:U} in the attached sheet is my desired answer even nothing/#N/A contains in cell {A3:J}. Just want to save record of previous fetched data. Thanks a lot you have tried for me.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have a formula in the cell "A3".
- When the formula is run, the table is imported to columns "A" to "J".
- You want to copy the imported values to columns "L" to "U" without the formula.
- You want to keep the imported values even when the formula returns `#N/A` in the cell "A3".

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When this script is run, when the cell "A3" is not `#N/A`, the values are copied from "A3:J" to "L3:U" without the formula. When the cell "A3" is `#N/A`, the values are not copied. By this, the previous values are kept.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const checkError = sheet.getRange("A3").getDisplayValue();
  if (checkError != "#N/A") {
    const srcRnge = sheet.getRange("A3:J" + sheet.getLastRow());
    srcRnge.copyTo(sheet.getRange("L3"), { contentsOnly: true });
  }
}
```

- About `Imported data is continuously changing after certain interval as fetched by Google sheet`, in this case, how about running the above script by the time-driven trigger? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) By this, the values are periodically updated.

#### Note:

- This script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Sir, If I am right, then the copied values from the range "A3:J" to "L3:U" will change every hour automatically without time-driven triggers. Please correct me.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `If I am right, then the copied values from the range "A3:J" to "L3:U" will change every hour automatically without time-driven triggers. Please correct me.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sir, I am accepting my English skills are poor. When the script runs manually or first time then copies the values to the cell "L3:U".  My query is that when the script runs next time automatically without any time-driven triggers? or is it mandatory to use time-driven triggers to run the script automatically as you provided above?

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `My query is that when the script runs next time automatically without any time-driven triggers?`, when you want to run the script by the time-driven trigger, please install it to the function. You can see the official document of this at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers When you install the function as the time-driven trigger, the script is automatically run.